# jQuery get dropdown rel value()

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

how do i get the dropdown rel="30" value?

```
  <select id="t_dermal_name">
     <option value="1" rel="30">Between Eyebrows</option>
       <option value="7" rel="30">Individual Line Softening</option>
       <option value="2" rel="30">Lip Contouring</option>
   </select>
```

jquery:

```
$("#t_dermal_name").change(onSelectChange);

function onSelectChange(){
    var selected = $("#t_dermal_name option:selected");     
    var output = "";
    if(selected.val() != 0){
        output = selected.rel();
    }
    $("#output").html(output);
}
```

Comment: `selected.rel()` should be `selected.attr('rel')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `:selected` selector to find the selected option and retrieve its `rel` value using the `attr()` method.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yAQhq/

```
$("#t_dermal_name").change(onSelectChange);

function onSelectChange(){
    var output = "",
        $this = $(this);

    if($this.val() != 0){
        output = $this.find('option:selected').attr('rel');
    }
    $("#output").html(output);
}
```

Comment: sorry.. quick question again. if you go to http://jsfiddle.net/yAQhq/3/ .. and how do i calculate output1 + output 2? do u know?

Comment: @boyee007: If you use the `+` operator with strings, it will simply concatenate the strings. In order to add the numbers together, you need to run `parseInt()` on them like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yAQhq/9/

Comment: it works great :) .. but if i select only one dropdown. in the #output its showing NaN?? i want even if i clik only one dropdown it shows 30 and if select both will sum the both output!

Comment: @boyee007: Come on, I can't do *everything* for you ;-]. If you see something like NaN, think about what's happening. Look up what `parseInt()` does and look up what it does if it encounters something it can't turn into an integer. Figure out what values it's trying to add together and try to add conditionals in there to get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

`$('select[name="X"] option[selected]').attr('data-xxx')` was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="xx" class="xxx" onchange="_name(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('rel'))">
  <option value="x" rel="xy">aa</option>
  <option value="xxx" rel="xyy">bb</option>
</select>


//for javascript
function _name(value,rel) {
alert(value+"-"+rel);
}
```

good works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **option:selected**

For example, i am using the follow code:

```
$("#mySelectId").on("change",function(){
   relValue =$("#mySelectId option:selected").attr("rel");
   console.log("You rel value is "+relValue);
});
```